# Samba4 CNAME. Не подключаются клиенты старше Windows 7/2008R2

Tags: dns, freebsd, samba, cname

Есть Samba version 4.2.2 на FreeBSD. Установлена в качестве резервного файлового сервера. Имя сервера zdata. A-запись в домене на zdata. Команда hostname тоже выводит zdata. По имени `\\zdata` клиенты всех версий нормально подключаются и  работают.

Но если прописать в домене CNAME на эту запись и указать в нём fileserver, то происходят странные вещи. По имени `\\fileserver` клиенты Windows 7/2008R2 подключаются без проблем, а клиенты более старших версий требуют ввода логина и пароля.

Конфиг smb4.conf

> [global]
>       workgroup = SZ
>       server string = FreeBSD backup server on Samba ver %v
>       security = ads
>       realm = SEZAR.LOCAL
>       socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072
>       use sendfile = no
>       recursive queries = yes
>
> ```
> idmap config * : backend = tdb
> idmap config * : range = 100000-2000000
> idmap config TEST : backend = rid
> idmap config TEST : range = 10000-2000000
> winbind enum users = yes
> winbind enum groups = yes
> winbind use default domain = yes
> winbind refresh tickets = yes
>
> restrict anonymous = 2
> log file = /var/log/samba4/log.%m
> max log size = 50
>
> winbind use default domain = yes
> template homedir = /usr/home/%D/%U
> template shell = /usr/local/bin/bash
> ```
>
> ; ---- Share Definitions ----
>
> [homes]
>           comment = Home Directories
>           browseable = no
>           writable = yes
>           valid users = %D\%S
>           create mask = 0600
>           directory mask = 0700
>           root preexec = mkdir -p /home/%D/%S
>
> [Backup]
>           path = /usr/home/backup
>           valid users = "@domain admins"
>           admin users = "@domain admins"
>           write list = "@domain admins"
>           read only = No
>           hide unreadable = Yes
>           locking = No

Как добиться, чтобы сервер корректно отвечал по CNAME записи?

Answer (score 1):

Для устранения проблемы необходимо зарегистрировать SPN с именем cname для этого сервера.